# finding filename matches between filenames in a data table and filenames in a directory

Tags: php

I am trying to write a script that queries a data table for file names and then finds a file name match in the results of a directory scan.
I already know that the filenames in the data table have the same format as the files in the directory I am scanning, i.e
all in lowercase with no spical character or spaces.

What appears to be happening is the "while loop" is only matching one record from the data table and the scan directory.
Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

The code I am working on is:

```
$sql = "SELECT CompanyName, ImageName, HotelID FROM conf_image_depository ORDER BY ImageName ASC";
$sqlfile = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$source = "boards/temp1";
$destination = "boards/temp2";
$scan = scandir('boards/temp1');
natcasesort($scan);
while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlfile)){
foreach($scan as $value) {
    if($value == $row['ImageName']){
        echo "File match copied: " .$value." - ". $row['ImageName']."</br>";
    } else {
        echo "File not copied: " .$value."</br>";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you need `scandir` even? Can you not just do something like `if(is_file('boards/temp1/' . $row['ImageName'])){...}`

Comment: Maybe you could use [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and/or [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) if your values are of the same format. Also maybe `reset($scan)` is missing after foreach loop.

Comment: @Chris Haas Hi, Your code works perfectly, many thanks. I was going to try and use the scan results to get the name of any matched files so I can later copy the matched files into another directory but because "if(is_file" does not give me the filename I'm at a loss has to how I can get this to work.

Comment: @ChrisHaas. Working. all I had to do was: while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlfile)){
if(is_file('boards/temp1/' . $row['ImageName'])){
  echo "File match copied:---- ". $row['ImageName']."</br>";
  copy($source."/".$row['ImageName'], $destination."/".$row['ImageName']);
 //} 
}else {
 echo "No File match</br>";
}
}

Comment: @DCJones, I'm fine if you just want to write that up as your own answer and accept it. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @ChrisHaas I have this works. All I needed to do was:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlfile)){ if(is_file('boards/temp1/' . 
$row['ImageName'])){ 
  echo "File match copied:---- ". $row['ImageName']."</br>"; 
copy($source."/".$row['ImageName'], $destination."/".$row['ImageName']); //} 
}else { 
  echo "No File match</br>"; } }
```